# Run robot keyword depending on existence of the element

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework, selenium2library

Is there a way to get info on whether an element exists on a page or not in Robot framework?

I would like to take one action if element exists on page, or another if element doesn't exist.

In Selenium, I would use `findElements()`, and that would return a list of elements, or an empty list if nothing is found.

In Robot, however, if I use `Get webelements` and nothing is found, test breaks with error:

```
ValueError: Element locator 'id=asdf' did not match any elements.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An approach is to get a boolean is the element in the page:

```
${present}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Page Should Contain Element   ${your_locator}
```

, and then control the flow based on the value:

```
Run Keyword If    ${present}    The keyword(s) if present
                  ...  ELSE     The keyword(s) if NOT present
```

Instead of `Page Should Contain Element` you could use `Element Should Be Visible`.

Comment: I expected 'Element should be visible' to break, but it works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It does "break" - in the sense that it will fail if the element is not present, but that's what the `Run Keyword If` is for - [it suppresses the normal pass/fail statuses of the called keywords, and returns a boolean instead](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status) - exactly for a flow you intend to use it for.

Comment: Aha, that clears it. Originally, I would set a variable to 'Get webelements', and then run keyword if this variable was this or that..